# Is there a faster method than looking through an array of strings for a string?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, list

Currently I am doing this:

```
        List<int> ID = new List<int>();
        int a = 0;
        string[] findWordHere = ...
        string[] findOtherWordHere = ...
        string word = "this";
        string otherWord = "that";

        foreach (string word in findWordHere)
        {
            foreach (string otherWord in findOtherWordHere)
            {
                if (word == otherWord)
                {
                    ID.Add(a + 1);
                }
            }
            a++;
        }
```

This is very time consuming. Is there a better way to do this, say with linq?

Comment: Just a simple plain old for loop would be faster

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. Add all items from the `findOtherWordHere` to `HashSet<string>` before the first loop, and use it for the lookup, like this:

```
ISet<string> lookup = new HashSet<string>(findOtherWordHere);
foreach (string word in findWordHere)
{
    if (lookup.Contains(word))
    {
        ID.Add(a + 1);
    }
    a++;
}
```

This runs in time proportional to the *sum* of lengths of `findWordHere` and `findOtherWordHere`, because `HashSet<string>` is built in linear time, and provides constant-time lookup capabilities.

Your original approach, on the other hand, runs in time proportional to the *product* of lengths of `findWordHere` and `findOtherWordHere`, because the worst case executes an inner loop to completion in each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Is Set<string> supposed to work in C# or is that supposed to be HashSet<string>?

Comment: @user2340818 Should be `ISet<String>`

Comment: @user2340818 I'm sorry for the typo, Magnus is right, I missed the `I` prefix in front of the name of the interface. `HashSet<string>` or `var` would perfectly work here as well, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `HashSet<string>`:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(findOtherWordHere);
var IDs = findWordHere
            .Select((w,i) => new {w,i})
            .Where(p => set.Contains(p.w))
            .Select(p => p.i)
            .ToList();
```

This provides the indexes of the words contained in the other list, without loops and with reasonable performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need arrays you can use `StringComparison` method:

```
            List<int> ID = new List<int>();

            int a = 0;

            string root = "that";
            string root2 = "that";

            bool result = root.Equals(root2, StringComparison.Ordinal);


            if (result)
            {
               ID.Add(a + 1);
            }
```

Or if you want to ignore case use `OrdinalIgnoreCase` keep in mind ordinal is the fastest way to compare two strings:

```
        List<int> ID = new List<int>();

        int a = 0;

        string root = "that";
        string root2 = "that";

        bool result = root.Equals(root2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);


        if (result)
        {
           ID.Add(a + 1);
        }
```